# How can I solve this equation by analytical method? $2^x=x+1$

Tags: exponential-function, real-numbers

How can I solve this equation by analytical method only for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

> $$2^x=x+1$$

I used the graphical method. I find $x=0, x=1$

[image]

Comment: I you really want to solve it systematically/analytically, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertw#Example_1. But IMO this is overkill.

Comment: You can show directly that $0$ and $1$ are roots.  Now you can use MVT (for example) to show these are the only real roots.

Comment: @gammatester "But IMO this is overkill." What is IMO

Comment: IMO = "In My Opinion"

Comment: @gammatester :)I thought IMO=İnternational Mathematical Olympiad :)